# jquery to grey and disable form elements on click IE

Tags: jquery, css, forms, jquery-ui

I have a form that requires some conditional form handling.  For example, when a user selects "yes they are applying for housing" I would like to enable some form elements and change the font color from grey to black.  Visually, I want the whole form to look disabled until the user selects "yes".

Now the trouble I ran into is, I have jquery that changes the class on a click from the grey class to the black or normal one.  I was able to implement this for multiple form sections other than the one below.  It works in chrome but not in IE and I validated my html but that did not resolve it.  I have troubleshooted this to the best of my abilities but cannot find the issue.

Here are the steps or check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vq1b1par/5/:

created css to grey out element

```
div.row.grey_me_homeless, div.col-lg-12.grey_me_homless p span,  p.form_legend.grey_me_homeless span{

color:grey !important;

 }
```

jquery to disable all form elements in section

```
$("div.col-lg-12.grey_me_homeless label :input, div.col-lg-12.grey_me_homeless textarea, .grey_me_homeless div :input, div.col-lg-12.grey_me_homeless").each(function(){

 $(this).prop('disabled', true);

 });
```

on click, change disabled elements to enabled and remove css classes

```
$('#emergency_yes').click(function () { 

  $("div.row.grey_me_homeless").removeClass().addClass("row contact_form color_font_homeless");
  $("div.col-lg-12.grey_me_homeless").removeClass().addClass("col-lg-12 color_font_homeless");
  $("p.form_legend.grey_me_homeless").removeClass().addClass("form_legend color_font_homeless");
  $("div.col-lg-12.color_font_homeless label :input, div.col-lg-12.color_font_homeless textarea, .color_font_homeless div :input").each(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
  })            
})
```

Comment: Try `$('#emergency_yes').change(function ()`

Comment: Maybe it's because jQuery prefers selectors shorter that the number of pixels in the known universe!

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I don't think the identifier is the issue because it works in chrome and I have the same naming convention in couple sections in my form and they all work in  IE 9

Comment: @Benjamin when I update the jfiddle to use the "change" method it does not work in IE 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much much simpler than the javascript in the question would have one believe.

First, delete the CSS directive for `grey_me_homeless` and allow the font color to be controlled by javascript.

Second, replace all the javascript with :

```
$(".row.contact_form .col-lg-12").find("input[type='radio']").on('click', function() {
    var state = this.value === 'yes';
    var textbox = state ? document.getElementById("immediate") : document.getElementById("employer_address_one");
    if(state || !$("input#immediate").is(":disabled")) {
        $(this).closest(".row").next("div").find("div, p, span, label").css('color', ['black','gray'][+!state]).end().find('input, button, textarea').prop('disabled', !state);
    }
    textbox.focus();
    textbox.scrollIntoView();
    scrollBy(0, -170);
}).eq(1).triggerHandler('click');
```

Explanation :

- a single click handler is attached to both radio buttons.
- which of the two buttons was clicked is determined by testing `this.value === 'yes'`
- the div containing all the elements of interest is found relative to the clicked radio button by the expresson `$(this).closest(".row").next("div")`
- the elements that need their text color to be changed are addressed with `.find("div, p, span, label").css('color', ['black','gray'][+state])`
- the elements that need to be enabled/disabled are addressed with `.find('input, button, textarea').prop('disabled', state)`
- lastly, `.eq(0).triggerHandler('click')` simulates a click on the "Yes" radio button, thereby establishing the initial state.

Should work in all the major browsers, including IE (tested in Opera).

With light adaptation, the code may be reusable in other sections of the form.

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq1b1par/10/)**

Comment: every looks good besides the last step.  In jsfiddle, the simluated click works but I haven't gotten to work in implementation.  If I have multiple row.contact_form .col-lg-12 would this impact eq(1)?

Comment: The full selector is `$(".row.contact_form .col-lg-12").find("input[type='radio']")`. Multiple `row.contact_form .col-lg-12` would only have an impact if others also had radio buttons, which I took not to be the case. If the code doessn't work in the full implementation, you need to start debugging - ask yourself why it doesn't work - does the click handler fire? - if it fires then why does it not give the right effect?

Comment: I decided to make the selector on the inner div tag, so `<div class="col-lg-12">` is now `<div class="col-lg-12" id='emergency'>`  I updated the js to use `$('#emergency')`.  Thank you.

Comment: I can't quite see why that's necessary but sometimes this is the sort of thing you have to do to get what you want. Cool!

Comment: Like I said previously, I have a lot iterations of checkbox and radio button "conditional" form elements.  When I take my second pass I'll try this approach again.

Comment: the original fiddle example we were using didn't include the text field "emloyer's address".  I've updated it with it and as you can see the address field is focused on page load. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vq1b1par/12/)[/link] any thoughts?